# SQL - Merging data from tables where the second table has multiple options

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, left-join

I am new to SQL and cant find exactly what I'm trying to do hence the question.

I have multiple oracle tables that I want to get different information from and usually its a direct link (1:1) based on key fields but for one table there are options. What I want to achieve is an address from Table 2 for every record on Table 1 (using select / from / where) . If there is a direct match use it but if there is no direct match use the All_Address record.

```
**Table 1: Acc / Acc Type / Balance**
1 Customer1       Shop      455.00        
2 Customer1       Home      212.66        
3 Customer2       Work      333.77       
4 Customer2       Home      12.00        
5 Customer3       Home      0.00         
6 Customer3       Work      123.00    

  **Table 2: Acc / Acc Type / Address**
1 Customer1       Shop      London  
2 Customer1       Home      Basingstoke  
3 Customer2       All       Birmingham
4 Customer3       Home      Nottingham
5 Customer3       All       Leicester

**Desired End Result**
1 Customer1       Shop      455.00       London
2 Customer1       Home      212.66       Basingstoke  
3 Customer2       Work      333.77       Birmingham
4 Customer2       Home      12.00        Birmingham 
5 Customer3       Home      0.00         Nottingham
6 Customer3       Work      123.00       Leicester
```

If I code below - it drops records 3, 4 & 6 because there is no direct match for those

```
Tab1.Acc_Name = Tab2.Acc_Name  AND  Tab1.Type = Tab2.Type
1 Customer1       Shop      455.00       London
2 Customer1       Home      212.66       Basingstoke  
5 Customer3       Home      0.00         Nottingham
```

If I code below then then I get duplicate on Customer 3 as its finding all possible combinations

```
  Tab1.Acc_Name = Tab2.Acc_Name AND ( Tab1.Type = Tab2.Type or Tab2.Type = ALL-Address)

1 Customer1       Shop      455.00       London
2 Customer1       Home      212.66       Basingstoke  
3 Customer2       Work      333.77       Birmingham
4 Customer2       Home      12.00        Birmingham 
5 Customer3       Home      0.00         Nottingham
6 Customer3       Home      0.00         Leicester     *duplicate 
7 Customer3       Work      123.00       Leicester
```

Is there a way to code this without getting the extra records (or will have to achieve some other way via an intermediate list). Thanks in advance / hopefully this is clear

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most efficient option is to `left join` the address table twice: once with the original `acc_type`, and then for the `'All'` type. You can then use `coalesce()` to prioritize one value against the other:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t20.address, t21.address) address
from table1 t1
left join table2 t20 on t20.acc = t1.acc and t20.acc_type = t1.acc_type
left join table2 t21 on t21.acc = t1.acc and t21.acc_type = 'All'
```

Another option is a correlated subquery with a row-limiting clause - or a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, x.*
from table1 t1
cross apply (
    select t2.adress
    from table2 t2
    where t2.acc = t1.acc and t2.acc_type in (t1.acc_type, 'All')
    order by case when t2.acc_type = t1.acc_type then 0 else 1 end
    fetch first 1 row only
) x
```

Comment: Thank you so much - will try it
Didn't realise you could left join the same table twice